# What is the expected rate of transactions per second that I should expect from Bitcoin's ZMQ service?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, unconfirmed-transactions, raw-transaction

I'm currently subscribed to the `hashtx` topic for Bitcoin's ZMQ service. I am noticing that I used to get an average of 3 transactions/second, but lately, I've been getting an average of 0.1 transactions/second. Is this a sign of bad peers to my bitcoind?

When I check on [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/charts/transactions-per-second?timespan=24h), I see that the number of Bitcoin transactions added to the mempool per second fluctuates between 2 and 11. Should the rate of transactions that I see from the ZMQ topic `hashtx` be the same as the rate of transactions added to the mempool?